# System.DmlException: Delete failed. CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, execution of BeforeDelete

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

**BACKGROUND**

I have a simple trigger which is meant to block a record from being deleted based on the record type.

I am using a [Trigger Handler by Kevin O'Hara](https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework)

**Trigger**

```
trigger InvoiceTrigger on Invoice__c (before delete) {
    new InvoiceTriggerHandler().run();    
}
```

**Trigger Handler**

```
public class InvoiceTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler {

    public InvoiceTriggerHandler() {}

    public override void beforeDelete(){

        for(Invoice__c invoice : (List<Invoice__c>) Trigger.new) {

            if (IsLocked(invoice)){
                invoice.addError('You cannot delete an Invoice record which is locked. Please contact your Salesforce Administrator.');
            }
        }   
    }

    private boolean IsLocked(Invoice__c invoice){
        return invoice.RecordTypeId == InvoiceUtils.getLockedRecordTypeId;
    }
}
```

**Trigger Unit Test**

```
@isTest
public class InvoiceTriggerTests {

    @isTest
    public static void InvoiceTrigger_Success(){

        // arrange
        Id invoiceId = TestDataFactory.createInvoice();

        // act
        Database.delete(invoiceId);

        // assert
        System.assert(true); // don't judge me :)
    }
}
```

But when I run the unit test I get this error message:

**Error Message**

> System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, InvoiceTrigger: execution
>   of BeforeDelete
>
> caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null
>   object
>
> Class.InvoiceTriggerHandler.beforeDelete: line 7, column 1
>   Class.TriggerHandler.run: line 43, column 1 Trigger.InvoiceTrigger:
>   line 2, column 1: []

**QUESTIONS**

1. What is actually causing the problem?
2. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `delete` context, your `trigger.new` will be null. Use `trigger.old` instead for `delete` events.

Comment: even with `before delete` ?

Comment: Always. There are no new records.

Comment: They haven't been deleted yet either? so the syntax is a little wonky...

Comment: @Robs "before" means "before initial commit", while "after" means "after initial commit" (see the [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) docs). Trigger.old doesn't exist in insert/undelete operations (because there was no previous state), and Trigger.new does not exist in delete (because after deletion, there is nothing left to commit). It's perfectly logical once you understand the above documentation.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks I will read the documentation. It was my first trigger, so asking dumb questions. RE: wonky syntax, I meant the `trigger.old` to get items before being deleted, because they are not *old* items yet?

Comment: @Robs old and new were probably a bad choice of words, but we're stuck with what we have. Think of "old" as "beforeDatabaseCommits" and "new" as "afterDatabaseCommits", which is really what they mean in this context. It's not wonky, in that sense, because in a "beforeDatabaseCommits" context, the records exist, but in the "afterDatabaseCommits" context, they don't (they've been deleted!).